# How to pass an ID from page to a user control's SelectParameter?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, webusercontrol, vwdexpress

Struggling in the foothills of learning about web user controls (in VWD Express with VB), I'm looking for an efficient way to pass the value of an ID from the page to the control, to be applied in a datasource's SelectParameters. Any quick tips to get me started?

Answer (score 0):

All child controls have access to their MasterPage via the `Master` property.  If you make a public method on your MasterPage's code behind that returns the id, you can call that method from the child page.

Comment: Tantalising! My user control is a dynamic menu (different sections of the website have different menu content) whose content depends on a sectionID from the calling aspx page read from its datasource. **Please** could you help with a VB example of a public method for the aspx page that exposes the current value of such a sectionID, and how the method would be called in the aspcx code?

Comment: BTW1: this is an aspx/ascx issue, rather than a masterpage/childpage issue.
BTW2: does the sectionID have to be passed to a control on the aspx page or can it be read directly to the public method in the code?

Comment: Direct reading might use the OnSelected event of the aspx's AccessDataSource passed into the ascx via the OnSelecting event of the ascx AccessDataSource? (How?)

Comment: I'm not versed well in VB, but I can tell you that this should be relatively easy.  It's probably better to push data from the parent page to the child user control.  Make a method on the UC that takes whatever value you want to pass from the parent to it.  Then when the event happens that will trigger this call, from the parent, just call the UC's method.  Then in the UC, you can handle that new data and make relevant changes.

Comment: Thanks for the steer. Sorry to ask, but how do I 'make a method on the user control'? Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: A User Control is like any other ASPX page, with a code-behind and markup.  If you make a method in the code-behind and mark it as public (I think VB uses public, too), any page that has your UC in it can call that method.  So if you declare `public string GetDataForUser(string user)` in your UC, in your main page (assuming a name of UC1 for your UC), you could call UC.GetDataForUser() and pass in a value from your main page.